# Setting unique default values for multiple UIPickerViews in the same View Controller Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a View Controller with two distinct UIPickerViews. The first is a contains seven names.  The second is a list of numbers(strings) from 1 to 100.  I want the default to be the last number in the list.

I have set the first UIPickerView's default value using the following method which I call in viewDidLoad.

```
[self.namePicker selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

This works just fine and my namePicker shows the third element when I run the code.

However, the following method call does not work for my second UIPickerView(also being called in viewDidLoad).

```
[self.numberPicker selectRow:99 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

There are no errors when I run, the numberPicker just appears with a default value of 1 (the first element) every time.

Comment: Are you sure that `self.numberPicker` isn't `nil` when you make this call?

Comment: No, I just checked it. It isn't nil. It is a UIPickerView object.

Comment: Another thing that happens is when I change the method to selectRow:1 instead of 99, it works and will set the default to the second element.  It is just not working with higher numbers like 99.

Comment: Some additional information about the problem is that the method  [self.numberPicker selectRow:5 inComponent:0 animated:YES]; works perfectly.  But the same method with selectRow:6 or anything beyond 6 reverts back to the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be that your UIPickerView dataSource and delegate methods are not differentiating between the two UIPickerViews. One way to handle that would be to give them separate tags in InterfaceBuilder and then use if and/or switch statements in your delegate and datasource methods:

```
#define kNamesPicker            0     // tag assigned in IB
#define kNumberPicker           1     // tag assigned in IB
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

if (pickerView.tag == kNamesPicker) {
}
else if (pickerView.tag == kNumberPicker) {
}
```

Once your delegate and datasource methods are sorted assigning values to the pickers should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I am using tags to distinguish between the two picker views with if statements in the delegate methods.

Comment: Have you checked that outlets and actions are unique? Using copy/paste these can get copied and result in multiple connections.

Comment: Yes, I checked that and all of the outlets/actions seem to be unique and correct.

Comment: Well - it seems obvious that your attempts to set your numberPicker somehow get routed to your namePicker. So, make sure that your tags are set correctly in your storyboard editor as well. Then you want to ascertain that there is absolutely no confusion of namePicker and numberPicker in your code. Go over every instance of the two and double-check that these weren't switched anywhere. Maybe post that code here.

Comment: Solved!  The problem was the tags were both set to 0 in storyboard editor.  I didn't realize I needed to set the tags in storyboard in addition, I thought that it might be overridden when declaring it programmatically.  Thank you!!